# Why does Grunt go into devDependencies?

Tags: npm, gruntjs

The Grunt documentation states that it (and any plugins) should be included in the `devDependencies` section of `package.json`. I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't see why. If I want to deploy a production version of my app, I still need to build it. And if I'm not building it, then why do I need Grunt?

In other words, imagine I pull my repo and say:

```
npm install --production
```

How do I now build my app if Grunt is in the `devDependencies` section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you using Grunt for?

Grunt is typically listed in the devDependencies because even when you are deploying it for production, you would still need to compile things like CoffeeScript, SASS, etc.

In our case, it looks like this: we check in latest changes to GitHub, and then our deploy scripts log into the server, pulls the latest code from GitHub master, runs npm install and then grunt production.

Then we have a clean production build of the site on the server.

Comment: If you are using `npm install` then what, if anything, would change if Grunt were listed in `dependencies` intead of `devDependencies`?

Comment: devDependencies are those that are used by the developer creating something (tests, build process, etc.).  Dependencies are the things that are needed at runtime.  I'm still a bit confused as to what exactly you're trying to do with Grunt.

Comment: I'm implementing a client-side app using our own CommonJS compliant framework, which is a pretty unusual use case. So I was trying to get a feel for how people typically use Grunt, and it wasn't obvious to me under which circumstances putting it into `devDependencies` would make a practical difference. As far as I can tell based on your and Adam's answer, it is probably more of a matter of convention than anything else. I gather that generally when Grunt is used, none of the Node packages (`devDependencies` or normal `dependencies`) are used in the production code.

Comment: Yes, unless you're building some sort of component or reusable module. Once Grunt has done it's thing, it is generally done.

Comment: Okay, sounds like the use of `devDependencies` is based more on a feeling that Grunt is a development tool than a practical desire to separate development and production dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Typically Grunt is used in development, it potentially handles testing, stylesheet pre-processors, javascript uglifying etc. You wouldn't distribute the Grunt related files as part of your production code, you would distribute the minified, tested, uglified code.

Comment: Right but in that case none of the modules in `dependencies` would be part of the production code either, right?

Comment: The modules in `dependencies` are indeed expected to be part of the production code. If my code uses the `foo` module, `foo` has to be in the `dependencies` section. If my tests use the `bar` module, it should instead appear in the `devDependencies` section. I believe that the statement about `grunt` belonging to the `devDependencies` section is based on the idea that your production code will have a `require('foo')` statement but not a `require('grunt')` statement